# How to make html button call external javascript drawing function

Tags: javascript, html

So my end goal is to have a simple webpage with say 10 buttons and each button, upon being clicked, calls a different javascript function. Each of these functions would be some sort of drawing. To start I'm just trying to get used to buttons calling external js files.

```
    <html>
<head>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="/Users/myname/Downloads/p5-release 3/empty-example/sketch.js">
  </script>

</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="setup();draw();">
        Draw me a circle!
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is my html file and below is the javascript file from which I am trying to call the function.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1300, 800);
}

function draw(){
    ellipse(100,100,80,80);
}
```

The button appears but after it is clicked nothing else happens. I would like the button to disappear after being clicked and only the ellipse to remain. Is this a possibility? I'm very new to web development (I started yesterday) so I'm sorry if this is a really easy problem to solve.

Comment: You might want to start with something more simple.   You also need to specify the canvas that the ellipse is being drawn on.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage

Comment: You can use javascript to set the css of elements to hide the button. give the button an id e.g. btnDraw and then simply say in javascript document.getElementById('btnDraw').css('display','none');

Comment: @NibbCNoble How do I go about specifying the canvas? When I was doing it without the condition of the button being pressed (Just calling the js functions in html) it was still drawing the ellipse with the same javascript code.

Comment: The failure lies inside your createCanvas and draw functions whose definition you did not post. Use console.log to determine which parts of your scripts work and which fail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can help but.. As shown you can call the second function `draw()` inside the `setup()` function,  [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pcek09bc/2/)

***Updated***

**HTML:**

```
<button id="myBtn">Draw me a circle!</button>
<div id="holder"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.onclick = function setup() {
    btn.remove();
    //alert("Function Setup!");
    document.getElementById("holder").innerHTML = '<canvas id="myCanvas" width="490" height="220"></canvas>';
    draw();
}

function draw() {
    //alert("Function Draw!");
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 70;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    context.stroke();
}
```

for more than one button just give each one of them an id and make a js var for each one:

```
btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");
btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");
```

***Note:***
code802, just something worthy to mention, I'd go with SVG drawing over canvas for:

- more support
- SVG is vector graphics mean no pixel-ating or blurry edges no matter how much you zoom on or what the screen resolution is.
- It can be external or css, img, object or inner-html or src.
- It could be cached in many cases.
- you can also manipulate it and animate it almost any way you want and anything you can do with canvas can do with svg

https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: This works really well in JSFiddle, but when I try to run it in sublime text  and my web browser nothing happens upon the button being clicked.

Comment: I just tried it locally and it does work on firefox and chrome but not IE, version 11

Comment: Did you put the HTML code in the body or is the entire html file as you stated? Also, is it necessary to load the external js file within html or does "myBtn" do that for you? Thanks again

Comment: It works both as inner javascrip in `<script>` or as external javascript file `external.js` again that's on firefox and chrome, not IE